# Selenium Path Doesn't make sense

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Ran a quick Script

```
from selenium import webdriver

path = r"C:/Users/andre/Desktop/chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(path)

driver.get('https://www.google.ca')
```

Output is

```
andrefu@LAPTOP-1011FFMG:/mnt/c/Users/andre/Desktop/Pardee Lab$ python3 Scrape_RNAfold.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/andrefu/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 76, in start
    stdin=PIPE)
  File "/home/andrefu/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 709, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "/home/andrefu/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 1344, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:/Users/andre/Desktop/chromedriver.exe': 'C:/Users/andre/Desktop/chromedriver.exe'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Scrape_RNAfold.py", line 7, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(path)
  File "/home/andrefu/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 68, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "/home/andrefu/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 83, in start
    os.path.basename(self.path), self.start_error_message)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver.exe' executable needs to be in PATH. Please see https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home
```

My chromedriver.exe is in my Desktop [image] So, I really don't know why its saying chromedriver isn't working.

I've tried different paths such as

```
path = 'C:\Users\andre\Desktop\chromedriver.exe'
path = 'C:\Users\andre\Desktop'
path = 'C:/Users/andre/Desktop/chromedriver.exe'
path = 'C:/Users/andre/Desktop'
```

Even putting my chromedriver in the same folder as my code `Scrape_RNAfold.py` Running it with the full path name and just the `driver = webdriver.Chrome()`.

I also tried it with the raw 'r' unicode before the string and with out it & using both single and double quotes. Could someone please help me identify where i'm going wrong?

Comment: Try to put it in the same folder as Python3 executable and use as `driver = webdriver.Chrome()`

Comment: @Andersson thanks for taking the time, in the original post you can see I tried that already. Here is [my output](https://imgur.com/a/oXaHZOC)

Comment: No. I mean not in the same folder as your script, but in the same folder with `python3.exe`

Comment: @Andersson sorry about that, I'm using WSL so my python3.exe is all the way in my /home. Here is [my output](https://imgur.com/NuHS00c)

Comment: @Andersson I have no idea what putting that into my python3.exe did, but it keeps giving me the Invalid argument. Note: It doesn't let me do anything now, I tried `pip freeze | grep splinter` and its giving me an invalid argument! (oh no i don't know what I did....) I deleted chromedriver.exe from that folder now.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be some mismatch between the *path seperator* (i.e. `/`) and the *quotes* (i.e. `""`)

You need to download the latest *ChromeDriver* from [ChromeDriver - WebDriver for Chrome](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads) and store it anywhere within your system. As you are on *Windows OS*, unzip the binary and perform the following:

- Within your program, pass the *Key* **executable_path** along with the *Value* referring to the **absolute path** of the *ChromeDriver*.
- While mentioning the **absolute path** of the *ChromeDriver*, either use *double back slashes* i.e. `\\`  within double quotes i.e. `" "`
- Or use *single back slash* i.e. `\` within single quotes i.e. `" "`
  along with the raw `r` switch as follows.
- So your code block will be:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver

  driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\Users\andre\Desktop\chromedriver.exe')
  driver.get('https://www.google.ca')
  ```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I tried that before, sorry I didn't mention it. Here is [my output](https://imgur.com/a/QD4M97f) You can see, exectuable_path isn't recognized as an argument. When removing executable_path, I get a similar error as before.

Comment: Edit: Noticed I spelt executable wrong, changed it and I get the [same error as before](https://imgur.com/X5z0VUS).

Comment: Can you update the mail question with the _error trace logs_ for further analysis?

Answer (score 0):

I found that using `driver = './chromedriver.exe'` the most effective way instead of having to give the PATH